# Android: SQLite database location

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a SQLite database but I can not find it using Android Device Monitor: the Data folder has a + sign, but when I click nothing appears.
I am using Android Studio Emulator with API 24.
Is there any way I can find the database using Android Device Monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look database data or schemes, you can try to use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug on the Android Device Monitor when used against emulators shipped with `API level 24+`. You can recreate your emulator with `API level 23` or below. If you still get the same issue, you can use the terminal like:

Run `adb root` to give you the root permissions.

To see devices connected:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554  device
```

Run `adb -s emulator-5554 shell` to link this emulator. On successful connection to the shell change directory to the databases path:

```
cd /data/data/<your app package name>/databases/
```

List the contents of that directory and confirm if your database is there:

```
$ ls
mydb.sqlite3
main.db
```

From there you can then pull your database with the following command:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.packagename.app/databases/mydb.sqlite3 /local/path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library by mindorks to view your sqlite database.

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

I hope this helps.